Black Background on PNGs 4.2
Guys I am absolutely losing my mind trying to get this to work, I am on Blender 4.2, and I have a transparent PNG placed on a surface of a rectangular prism as a material image texture. I cannot get rid of the black background to save my life, no video on YouTube or forum response has answered this question since there always seems to be a setting that has changed and is no longer covered. Blender has apparently changed every possible route to solving, and I cannot believe it is this difficult to overlay an image on to an object in a 3D program. In photoshop this is done in 5 seconds on extruded objects with vanishing point filters - yet in a program seemingly designed for this very thing, you can't solve it with a few steps?
I need to be completely walked through this in order to understand, no shorthand if you can help it

Complete walk through would require information about what exactly you are doing and how. There is no way to know what specific look you are after since you haven't provided any info on that.

Sorry, but your question is lacking a lot of information as @MartynasŽiemys already pointed out. First of all we do not know if your transparent parts show black because you do not use the Alpha channel or if you do, you are probably in EEVEE instead of Cycles where Alpha transparency does not work out of the box but needs specific settings. Then we do not know if you want to place the image with transparency over an existing material on the same face(s) like a sticker where the original material shows through the transparent areas - this would not be possible with two separate materials.

Oh, I thought, there are no alpha blend settings in 4.2 anymore, but they are there, it seems only in Cycles. I think that's a bug, I will report it. If one is in EEVEE, there is no Settings subpanel in Viewport Display panel in material properties...

@MartynasŽiemys Yes, relax, I'm not criticising your answer. Yep, I did not think about 4.2 blend mode settings because I usually do not use EEVEE for anything. I do not doubt there is an Alpha channel, still it is possible he wants to place a second material over another on the same face which is simply not possible in Blender. I just wanted to make clear to him that if your answer was not the solution in this case, it might be helpful if he gives more information. Or in general it is helpful to get more information on how the materials are set up to rule out all possibilities.

No it seems I made a mistake. There seems to be a confusing problem with the Blend Mode settings getting hidden.

@MartynasŽiemys I guess the Blend Mode settings are getting hidden when using EEVEE since they are not used anymore and in Cycles they are still there because EEVEE is used for the Material Preview, i.e. some of the material settings for Cycles would not apply for the preview. Note however that the Blend Mode "Opaque" is still there, but you cannot select it anymore.

The settings do affect transparency in EEVEE viewport. https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/126369 Reported a bug, let's see what the devs say.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Use alpha channel in the image as transparency:

If you are not using Principled BSDF, you can mix other shaders with Transparent BSDF and use the alpha as factor for the Mix Shader node:

You may want to choose an appropriate Render Method(EEVEE)/Blend Mode(Cycles) in the material properties:


haha well that worked like a charm and I feel very silly ! Thanks for the help !!

Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, while it's nice to say "Thanks" as a comment, it would be better instead to upvote the post that helped you. If you feel it completely solved your issue, consider marking it as accepted. This way it will mark your question as having a proper answer, reward the answer's author with points, and make the answer easier to find for the next people encountering the same issue.
